# Homepage sidebars (menus or blocks/modules)

Tags: routes, navigation

Is it always recommended to use Menus for the sidebars on the homepage for example? Or would you sometimes use blocks and manually add the links? In which circumstances would you for example create a custom module for the sidebar which is to display links?

Comment: It is always better to use the menus so that you can control it within the drupal interface and use different functions.

Comment: Thank you!!! Is it acceptable to have lots of menus for one site? Eg. Quick Links Menu, External Links Menu, etc?

Comment: yes it is quite normal to have it that way.